# Posting data and params using $resource using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a angular service which has custom methods like this

```
appServices.factory('RuleSets', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('', {}, {
            query: {
                method:'GET',
                isArray:true,
                url: '../data/routing-ruleset-:ruleSetId.json'
            },
            unschedule: {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '../data/unschedule:ruleSetId.json'
            },
            schedule: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {ruleSetId: ':ruleSetId', date: ':date'},
                url: '../data/schedule.json'
            }
        });
    }]);
```

I am having issues posting data using my custom methods

```
RuleSets.unschedule({ruleSetId: ruleSetId});
```

and

```
RuleSets.schedule({date: $scope.formattedDate, ruleSetId: $scope.selectedRuleSet})
```

The behavior i see int he former is that the ruleSetId url parameter does not get populated if it is a POST request. In the latter, I do not know how to populate the request parameters if it is a post request (I am aware the code written is incorrect), as what I have tried in my services function does not work. I would also like to send data as part of the request to 'schedule'. I have seen how I can do this by say doing this

```
var ruleSets = new RuleSets();
ruleSets.id =  $scope.selectedRuleSet
ruleSets.$save();
```

but how do I do it with a custom method?

Should I rather be using $http or not so many custom methods. I like the structure that custom methods provides, so i'd like to keep it like that if possible.

Comment: The way you call your resource methods looks good to me but, is it normal that `unschedule` does not have the `params` option?

Comment: @glepretre, I would like to post data back to that method too and not parameters. I'm just trying to find something that works (with POSTing) right now though